# powershell variable updates for .msu files but not for .exe files

Tags: powershell

I have .msu and .exe files in a folder.  I'm creating INI files for each.  For the .msu files it runs just fine.  For the .exe files it processes the first one then it skips the rest of them.  The code

```
$INIFileName = ($strItem -replace ".$fileExtention",".ini")
```

seems to be the issue.  It doesn't replace any of following .exe extentions to the .ini format after the initial .exe file

Output:

```
  ** Creating .INI files for any msu's that don't have one ** 

Original file name with .exe: kb0000001.msu
New INI file name with .ini  : kb0000001.ini
Original file name with .exe: kb0000002.msu
New INI file name with .ini  : kb0000002.ini
Original file name with .exe: kb0000003.msu
New INI file name with .ini  : kb0000003.ini

  ** Creating .INI files for any exe's that don't have one ** 

Original file name with .exe: kb0000004.exe
New INI file name with .ini  : kb0000004.ini
Original file name with .exe: kb0000005.exe
New INI file name with .ini  : kb0000005.exe
  C:\Temp\PatchBundle\kb0000005.exe exists.  Skipping.
Original file name with .exe: kb0000006.exe
New INI file name with .ini  : kb0000006.exe
  C:\Temp\PatchBundle\kb0000006.exe exists.  Skipping.
PS C:\temp\PatchBundle>
```

Test files: (Created in code)
kb0000001.msu
kb0000002.msu
kb0000003.msu
kb0000004.exe
kb0000005.exe
kb0000006.exe

Code:

```
## Create test files
Function CreateTestFiles ($strDestPath)
{
    If (-not(Test-Path "$strDestPath\kb0000001.msu"))
    {
        New-Item ("$strDestPath\kb0000001.msu")
        New-Item ("$strDestPath\kb0000002.msu")
        New-Item ("$strDestPath\kb0000003.msu")
        New-Item ("$strDestPath\kb0000004.exe")
        New-Item ("$strDestPath\kb0000005.exe")
        New-Item ("$strDestPath\kb0000006.exe")
    }
}


## Create INI's for files
Function CreateINI ($fileExtention, $SPNumber, $strDestPath)
{
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Magenta `n " ** Creating .INI files for any $fileExtention's that don't have one **" `n

## Obtain a list of KB*.extention files.
$arrList = get-childitem -path $strDestPath -name -filter "kb*.$fileExtention"

## If extention list is empty, abort
If ($arrList.Count -eq 0) 
{ 
    write-host -foregroundcolor "red" "  No KB*.$fileExtention files found to work with."
}
Else {

    ## Start looping through the list stored in the array
    Foreach ($strItem in $arrList) {

        ## Determine the patch INI name with path
        Write-Host "Original file name with .exe: $strItem"
        $INIFileName = ($strItem -replace ".$fileExtention",".ini") 
        $strDestINI = "$strDestPath\$INIFileName"
        Write-Host "New INI file name with .ini  : $INIFileName"
        ## If the destination patch INI already exists, skip processing to avoid overwriting.
        If (Test-Path $strDestINI) {
            write-host -ForegroundColor Red "  $strDestINI exists.  Skipping."
        }

        ##  Else, create a new patch INI from the template.    
        Else {
            ## Gets KB Number from file name
            $KBNumber = ((($strItem -replace ".$fileExtention","").ToUpper()).TrimStart("KB"))

            ## Creates INI file
            #OutputINIFile $fileExtention $KBNumber $SPNumber $strDestINI

            ## If File Extention is MSU, checks if file needs the wsusscan.cab file pulled and renamed
            ## Checks:  Ignores file names with v. Example:  KB1234567v2.msu
            ## Checks:  Length of file name is greater than 13 chararacters.  Example: KB1234567IE7.msu
            If (($fileExtention = 'msu') -and `
                ($strItem -notlike '*v*') -and `
                ($strItem.Length -gt 13))
            {
                ## Create the -scan.cab file
                #Create-scanCab $KBNumber $strDestPath $strItem
            }
        }
    }
    }
}

Clear
## Main
## Variables in the script
$strDestPath = "C:\Temp\PatchBundle"
[Void][System.IO.Directory]::CreateDirectory($strDestPath)
$fileExtentions = "msu", "exe"

## Gets the service pack # based on the OS selected
$SPNumber = 2

CreateTestFiles $strDestPath

## Create .INI for all extentions files
Foreach ($extention in $fileExtentions) 
{CreateINI $extention $SPNumber $strDestPath}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In line 55 you are assigning extention as msu inside if condition(for msu files this won't effect but for the second exe file extension replacement won't happen because of that),like this:

```
   If (($fileExtention = 'msu') -and `
```

I think you meant

```
   If (($fileExtention -eq 'msu') -and `
```